# permission issue with docker and pipework

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, docker

I have issue using **Docker** with **pipework** for more advanced networking settings:

pipework eth2 $(docker run -d hipache /usr/sbin/hipache) 50.19.169.157/24

```
sudo: pipework: command not found
```

sudo pipework tap2 $(docker run -d ajn_sshd) 192.168.2.221/24

```
Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.12/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied
sudo: pipework: command not found
```

pipework tap2 $(docker run -d ajn_sshd) 192.168.2.221/24

```
Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.12/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied
bash: /usr/local/bin/pipework: Permission denied
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of tapx and ethx, I should have used **bridge interfaces**.

pipework uses bridge interfaces to bridge between the two virtual interfaces: one inside the container, **renamed as 'ethx'**, and one in the docker host **vethxxxxx**.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the -i option for sudo, which keeps your PATH.

`sudo -i pipework eth2 $(sudo docker run -d hipache /usr/sbin/hipache) 50.19.169.157/24`